# How do you remove git version 1.9.4msysgit.2 from windows 7?

Tags: windows, git

You'd think this would be as simple as heading into Programs and Features and removing it like anything else, but it isn't. Since it wasn't listed there, I deleted "Git" folders from both Program Files and Program Files (x86). However, after doing so and clearing my recycle bin, using "git --version" in a command prompt still insisted that it was installed. No big deal; I probably just needed to reboot my computer, right?

Nope. Tried that. It still claims that version of git is installed, yet I'm unable to find it anywhere on my computer. Other things I've tried is installing git 2.6.1 and 2.6.2. Using "git --version" still insists that I'm on 1.9.4. Checking Programs and Features after installing either of those two versions will claim that I'm on whichever of those two versions I most recently installed. While googling an answer for this and following along with various guides to try to resolve this, I downloaded a package manager for windows called "chocolatey." After installing git 2.6.2 through this and confirming that it was successful, the "git --version" command is still adamant that I'm on version 1.9.4.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `echo %PATH%`. This should narrow down the places to look.

Most probably you've got something like TortoiseGit or msys, or Cygwin installed which may be coming up first on your `PATH` which means they'll be used first.

Try moving your new git 2.6.1 paths to the front of `PATH` so that they'll be found and used first (you'll need to close and re-open any terminals you have open).

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right. Removing the Git folder from C:\RailsInstaller, which was the first result after using echo %PATH%, cleared this up.